# Custom ordering of ranks in MPI_Group

Tags: c, mpi

Ranks of processes in `MPI_Group` are ordered based on ranks of input processes by shifting down the ranks such the minimum group rank is zero. Is it possible to order the ranks of processes in `MPI_Group` by myself?

In the code below, actual and desired orderings are shown.

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    MPI_Group world_group; 
    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_group);

    int ranks[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    MPI_Group group;
    MPI_Group_incl(world_group, 3, ranks, &group);

    /* actual order */
    // old_rank[0] = 1 -- new_rank[0] = 0
    // old_rank[1] = 2 -- new_rank[1] = 1
    // old_rank[2] = 3 -- new_rank[2] = 2

    /* desired order */
    // old_rank[0] = 1 -- new_rank[0] = 1
    // old_rank[1] = 2 -- new_rank[1] = 2
    // old_rank[2] = 3 -- new_rank[2] = 0

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you write is wrong, the ranks are not shifted. They are based on the order of the ranks array. Or to cite the standard:

> The function MPI_GROUP_INCL creates a group newgroup that consists of the n processes in group with ranks ranks[0],. . ., ranks[n-1]; **the process with rank i in newgroup is the process with rank ranks[i] in group.**

So you just do:

```
int ranks[3] = {3, 1, 2};
```

Allthough it somehow feels fishy that you omit the original process with rank 0.